# php-pdftk permission issue on debian 9

Tags: php, debian, pdftk

I'm facing an issue with php-pdftk on debian 9. 
I want to edit and merge some PDF files, but I can't save it.
I get the following error when I call `$pdf->saveAs('some_path.pdf');`

[image]

I already tried solutions from [this](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk/issues/150) post, but not working.

Someone already solved this problem ?
Thanks